# How to make a JSON output like this?

Tags: php, json

**My desired output**

```
{"rowcount":4
[{"provider_id":"1","provider_name":"Crecent Computers","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks"]}],[{"provider_id":"4","provider_name":"Testing Co. LLC","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks"]}],[{"provider_id":"41","provider_name":"Itiology","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks","All IT Services"]}],[{"provider_id":"42","provider_name":"ITiology","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks","All IT Services","Website Design "]}]}
```

**My desired output end**

**My current JSON output**

```
{"rowcount":4,"0":[{"provider_id":"1","provider_name":"Crecent Computers","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks"]}],"1":[{"provider_id":"4","provider_name":"Testing Co. LLC","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks"]}],"2":[{"provider_id":"41","provider_name":"Itiology","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks","All IT Services"]}],"3":[{"provider_id":"42","provider_name":"ITiology","sub_name":["Hardware","Software","Networks","All IT Services","Website Design "]}]}
```

**JSON Output end**

**PHP CODE**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from service_provider where servicecategory_id = '1'");


if ($counter = mysqli_query($con, "select * from service_provider where servicecategory_id = '1'"))
{
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($counter);

    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($counter);
}

$data_points = array();
$subcatArray = array();

$data_points["rowcount"] = $rowcount;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $subcatresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sub_name, price FROM sub_services WHERE provider_id = " . $row['provider_id']);
    while($subcatrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc(  $subcatresult))
    {
        $subcatArray[] = $subcatrow['sub_name'];
        unset($subcatrow);
        $subcatrow = array();
    }


    $data_points[][] = [
        'provider_id' => $row['provider_id'],
        'provider_name' => $row['provider_name'],
        'sub_name' => $subcatArray
    ];

    // array_push("totalRow",$data_points, $point);
}


echo json_encode($data_points);
```

**PHP CODE END**

Comment: You're desired JSON is not actually valid. You should add a key like `providers` and put nested arrays inside them. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you desired output json is an invalid json. you can check this json out valid or not in the http://jsonviewer.stack.hu. json or xml has it's own patterns.

Answer (score 0):

So i found out that my desired output is invalid. Sorry I'm new to PHP.

I removed this line

```
$data_points["rowcount"] = $rowcount;
```

and made this

```
$data_points[][] = [
        'provider_id' => $row['provider_id'],
        'provider_name' => $row['provider_name'],
        'sub_name' => $subcatArray
    ];
```

into this

```
$data_points["Rows"][] = [
        'provider_id' => $row['provider_id'],
        'provider_name' => $row['provider_name'],
        'sub_name' => $subcatArray
    ];
```

I got the output pretty much close to what i need. Thanks guys!